# Where is the PyQt/PySide event-loop running?

Tags: python, events, pyqt, event-handling, pyside

If I open a Python interpreter and enter the following lines:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = QtGui.QLineEdit()
w.show()
```

then a text entry widget appears. I can interact with it while I interact with the interpreter. If I had attached any event handlers, they would be called too.

If I do `import time; time.sleep(10)`, the Widget becomes unresponsive for 10 seconds.

If I run `app.exec_()`, that call blocks until I close the application.

My question is: what is the point of running `app.exec_()` if the widget is already responding to events? What is different? Is it just a way of preventing the application from closing while still servicing Qt's event loop (`while True: pass` would cause the event loop to block, as we understand from doing `time.sleep(10)`)

I would also like to understand where Qt has hooked into CPython that allows the interpreter and the GUI to be active. I'm aware that Python 2 (and possibly 3?) has a so-called `PyOS_InputHook` mechanism, which is called roughly 10 times a second. IPython uses this to run a GUI (with lots of effort to handle GUI events faster than 10 times a second). Is the same thing happening when I instantiate a `QApplication`? If so, again, what is the point of calling `app.exec_()`

Comment: What Python interpreter are you using? IPython or actually straight python? Presumably you don't get the same behaviour if you were to put the same code in a .py file and run it?

Comment: this occurs with both Python and IPython. If I put the code in a .py file and import that file into a session, I get the behavior above. If I `python script.py`, the script finishes and the gui window disappears pretty much instantly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use PyQt/PySide in an interactive session, the event processing is set up automatically in the background in a way that allows you to interact directly with the objects. So for example you could create and show a window, and then add other widgets to it from within the python shell whilst the window is still visible. This behaviour is specific to interactive sessions, though - it's only there to allow you to easily experiment with things without the hassle of setting up the event processing yourself.

According to the PyQt Docs, `PyOS_InputHook` is used to process events whilst the interactive interpreter is waiting for user input (see: [Using PyQt5 from the Python Shell](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/python_shell.html?highlight=pyos_inputhook#using-pyqt5-from-the-python-shell)) - and presumably a similar mechanism is also used by PySide.

For a normal PyQt/PySide application started from a script, you **must** explicitly call `app.exec_()` in order to start event handling. Otherwise, the script will just exit as soon as all the code has been executed (i.e. just like any other python script would).

(For a more in-depth look at Qt's event-processing, see: [Threads, Events, QObjects](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#6c678d88cb4b92f3adbd4d6182d6ea78)).